# to get last row of each day from excel sheet

Tags: excel

i need to find the last record of each day in excel if there are multiple entries

> *******intention is to get EOD balance ROW OF EACH DATE********

like i have data in excel something like this

```
date             CR_DR amount EOD balance
----------------------
7/9/2017 19:09  CR       10       10
7/10/2017 18:37 CR       25       35
7/10/2017 21:06 DR       10       25
7/11/2017 19:21 CR       15       40  
7/15/2017 14:17 DR       20       20
7/17/2017 17:12 CR       100     120
7/18/2017 7:44  DR       30       90
7/18/2017 14:08 DR       50       40
7/18/2017 16:52 CR       120     160
```

for which i need to get data like (get the last row of each day)

```
7/9/2017 19:09  CR       10       10
7/10/2017 21:06 DR       10       25
7/11/2017 19:21 CR       15       40  
7/15/2017 14:17 DR       20       20
7/17/2017 17:12 CR       100     120
7/18/2017 16:52 CR       120     160
```

[image: adding output of formula applied]

[image: data post updated comments]

Comment: u may need vba to do this

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Enter the following formula in `Cell F2`

```
=IFERROR(MAX(IF(INT($A$2:$A$10)=INT(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, FREQUENCY(IF(EXACT(INT($A$2:$A$10), TRANSPOSE(INT($F$1:F1))), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$10), ROW($A$2:$A$10)), ""), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$10), ROW($A$2:$A$10))), 0))),$A$2:$A$10,0)),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required.

Then in `Cell G2` enter

```
=VLOOKUP($F2,$A$2:$D$10,COLUMN(C1)-COLUMN($A$1),FALSE)
```

Drag this formula across (to right) till `Cell I2` and down as required.

See image for reference.

[image]

### Solution 2

Instead of using an ugly looking long formula, here we'll use a helper column.

In `Cell F2` enter the following formula

```
=MAX(IF(INT($A$2:$A$10)=INT(A2),$A$2:$A$10,0))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required.

Then in `Cell G2` enter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$10,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$F$2:$F$10),0,0),0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

Finally, in `Cell H2` enter

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$D$10,COLUMN(C1)-COLUMN($A$1),FALSE)
```

Drag this formula across (to right) till `Cell J2` and down as required.

See image for reference.

[image]

***EDIT :*** As per comment.

Instead of

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$D$10,COLUMN(C1)-COLUMN($A$1),FALSE)
```

use below formula in `Cell H2`

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$10,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10=$G2,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,1,1))+1)))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag this formula across (to right) till `Cell J2` and down as required. Drag/Copy down as required.

***Screen-Shot :***

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why the `INDEX` is required around the `COUNTIF`? Does that turn it into the range that `MATCH` can search?

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier - I am confused on your question, are you asking me whether I know or do you want to know why it is used?

Comment: Because I don't know (I tried it without, and it gave an error), and I was curious if you did. :-)  I'm always interested to know more of WHY certain things work the way they do in Excel so I can try them in other situations. :-p

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier - Purpose of using `INDEX` around `COUNTIF` is to use it as a normal formula that can be used just by pressing `Enter`. You can remove `INDEX` around `COUNTIF` but then you have to use formula as an array formula i.e. by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+ `Enter`.

Comment: hey Mrig thanks for this great help .. one thing is, the output of this formula has some issue with my input data. could you please check how can I make it work perfectly... thanks in advance for this help :)

I am unable to paste the screen shot here .

Comment: @user1708054 - Upload the screen shot online and share link here.

Comment: hi Mrig, I have tried replacing it with your comments but the output is still not as desired. please guide me how is to be done. attaching the screen shot to my question. thanks in adv :)

Comment: @user1708054 - I've added a screen shot in my answer, I am getting different and probably correct results. As per screen shot in your question, formula in `Cell H3` seems okay, can you also share formula being used in `Column I & J`.

Comment: sorry Mrig, got into something else.. will check and update you :)

Comment: @user1708054 - No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is crude and I'm sure there are "proper" ways to do this, but it works for what you want to do. I used columns A thru D for the data. In column F I used the formula =Left(A3,5) and copied it down. You will have to modify according to your situation. Hope this helps or gets you headed in right direction. Good Luck

```
Sub FindLast()
'FIND LAST LISTED DATE AND COPY
Dim myCount, myCount2, myRange, myRow, x, y, r
r = 3

myCount = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2

    MsgBox "Rows used are   " & myCount

For x = 3 To myCount Step 1

    y = Range("F" & x).Value
    MsgBox "Value of x is  " & x
    MsgBox "Value of y is  " & y

        myCount2 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F3:F" & myCount + 2), y)
        MsgBox "myCount2 value is  " & myCount2

Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A" & x & ":" & "A" & x + myCount2 - 1))
myRow = Range("A" & x + myCount2 - 1).Row

    MsgBox "myRow number is:  " & myRow
    MsgBox CDate(Max_date)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & r).Value = Max_date
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & r).Value = Range("B" & myRow).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & r).Value = Range("C" & myRow).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & r).Value = Range("D" & myRow).Value

    r = r + 1

    If myCount2 <> 1 Then
            x = x + (myCount2 - 1)
        Else
            x = x
        End If

Next x


End Sub
```

You will notice there are a lot of message boxes. I used these to test the parameters and make sure they were coming out like I wanted. When you are comfortable with how it's working, just comment them out.

Also, the output is set to I3 thru L8 for the example you posted. Please make sure to edit these if your real sheet has any data in these areas. My suggestion is test first to get familiar with what's happening. I did't put any "failsafes" or "exits" in, as I ran out of time. There are plenty of examples on this site to help with that.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It requires entering the dates in column A (I didn't feel motivated enough to figure out how to pull the unique ones out), but if you are feeling spunky, you could use some array formulas. :-)

```
Column A    Column B        C    D  E
7/9/2017    7/9/2017 19:09  CR  10  10
7/10/2017   7/10/2017 21:06 DR  10  25
7/11/2017   7/11/2017 19:21 CR  15  40
7/15/2017   7/15/2017 14:17 DR  20  20
7/17/2017   7/17/2017 17:12 CR  100 120
7/18/2017   7/18/2017 16:52 CR  120 160
```

Enter dates in column A.  Then in column B enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Date,SMALL(IF(ROUNDDOWN(Date,0)=$A1,ROW(Date)-1),COUNTIFS(Date,">="&$A1,Date,"<"&$A1+1))),"")
```

closing out of the cell with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER so that the formula in the formula bar looks like

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Date,SMALL(IF(ROUNDDOWN(Date,0)=$A1,ROW(Date)-1),COUNTIFS(Date,">="&$A1,Date,"<"&$A1+1))),"")}
```

Note: it does not work to enter the curly braces yourself. ;-)  You must close out of the cell with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER!

The `Date` in the formula is a named range - I don't like typing `$A$2:$A$10` all the time.  If you don't want to do named ranges, replace `Date` with `$A$2:$A$10` or your applicable range.

Column C:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CR_DR,SMALL(IF(ROUNDDOWN(Date,0)=$A1,ROW(Date)-1),COUNTIFS(Date,">="&$A1,Date,"<"&$A1+1))),"")
```

Same thing - close out of cell with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER.  Named range again for `CR_DR`, same rules as for `Date` above.  Copy/paste the for the other columns, changing the range that `INDEX` is searching as appropriate for the column you want.

Explanation: `ROUNDDOWN` removes the time from the date in your source data so that it can match it to the date in column A.  If the date matches, its row (-1 because the row number of A2 is 2, but it is the first item in `$A$2:$a$10`) is put into an array for the `SMALL` function.  This chooses the nth smallest item from the array, defined by the `COUNTIFS` function, which counts how many dates fall between the date in column A and the day after the date in column A (thus actually giving you the largest item).  `INDEX` then uses the range and looks up the row number that `SMALL` delivered to it.  If it errors out, the cell is blank.

If you don't want to hand-enter specific dates, auto-fill for all dates and it will simply be blank on dates with nothing:

```
7/9/2017    7/9/2017 19:09  CR  10  10
7/10/2017   7/10/2017 21:06 DR  10  25
7/11/2017   7/11/2017 19:21 CR  15  40
7/12/2017               
7/13/2017               
7/14/2017               
7/15/2017   7/15/2017 14:17 DR  20  20
7/16/2017               
7/17/2017   7/17/2017 17:12 CR  100 120
7/18/2017   7/18/2017 16:52 CR  120 160
```

Comment: You could also use a helper column with this solution like Mrig did.  You would put `=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ROUNDDOWN(Date,0)=$A1,ROW(Date)-1),COUNTIFS(Date,">="&$A1,Date,"<"&$A1+1)),"")` in column B (still using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER) to get your row number and then the columns next to it would simply be `=INDEX (YourRange,$B1)`, no CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER required.